# audio jack server: can't get buffer

Tags: c, audio, compiler-errors, jack

experts...

I have a little questions. I want to create a client for Jack audio server and when I want to get a buffer to write into it like this:

`sample_t *out = (sample_t *) jack_port_get_buffer(output_port, nframes);`

i get this:

> error: 'sample_t' was not declared in this scope

I don't know what to do because I included the header(jack/jack.h) correctly and I can create a client and I can open ports.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you typedef the original variable name of jack?

```
typedef jack_default_audio_sample_t sample_t;
```

Most of the time, `sample_t` will be too generic for a variable name in a library, that's why they "rename" it to sample_t.